# subsetting and renaming vector elements

Tags: r, subset, renaming

I must be doing some naive mistake, but cannot figure out why my code is not working as intended:

```
testVector<- c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b')

names(testVector)<- replicate(n = 6, expr = 'temp')

##The following does not work, but does not give any error:
names(testVector[testVector=='a'])<- replicate(n = 3, expr = 'tempA')
#
names(testVector[testVector=='a'])
# [1] "temp" "temp" "temp"
```

The subsetting part seem to be right, I don't understand why it is not changing names though. What am I missing?

Comment: Miss-placed the parenthesis. Try `names(testVector)[testVector == 'a'] <- replicate(n = 3, expr = 'tempA')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to subset the `names`

```
names(testVector)[testVector=='a'] <- replicate(n = 3, expr = 'tempA')

testVector
#tempA tempA tempA  temp  temp  temp 
#  "a"   "a"   "a"   "b"   "b"   "b"
```